# UIScrollView con UIPageControl no queda centrado correctamente SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode

Actualmente estoy necesitando tener un UIPageControl haciendo uso del UIScrollView
para poder tener un efecto de carrosuel [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que las UIView no quedan centradas cada una un ejemplo mas practico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me queda parte de la segunda vista como parte de la primera

Mis clases son :

```
class InitialViewController: CommonViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!{
    didSet{
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}


var presenter = InitialPresenter()
var slides:[Slide] = [];            

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.slides = createSlides()
    self.setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.presenter.wfm = WorkflowManager.init(navigationController: self.navigationController)
}


func createSlides() -> [Slide] {

    let slide1:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewSlide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide1.imgCenterSlide.image = UIImage(named: "icono_transferencia_carrusel")
    slide1.strLblTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblTitleSlideOne_INTIAL",comment:"")
    slide1.strLblSubTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblSubTitleSlideOne_INTIAL",comment:"")

    let slide2:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewSlide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide2.imgCenterSlide.image = UIImage(named: "icono_pago_carrusel")
    slide2.strLblTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblTitleSlideTwo_INTIAL",comment:"")
    slide2.strLblSubTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblSubTitleSlideTwo_INTIAL",comment:"")

    let slide3:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewSlide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide3.imgCenterSlide.image = UIImage(named: "icono_consulta_carrusel")
    slide3.strLblTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblTitleSlideTree_INTIAL",comment:"")
    slide3.strLblSubTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblSubTitleSlideTree_INTIAL",comment:"")

    let slide4:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewSlide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide4.imgCenterSlide.image = UIImage(named: "icono_simulador_carrusel")
    slide4.strLblTitle.text  = NSLocalizedString("strLblTitleSlideFour_INTIAL",comment:"")
    slide4.strLblSubTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("strLblSubTitleSlideFour_INTIAL",comment:"")

    slide1.strLblTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText
    slide1.strLblSubTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText

    slide2.strLblTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText
    slide2.strLblSubTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText

    slide3.strLblTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText
    slide3.strLblSubTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText

    slide4.strLblTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText
    slide4.strLblSubTitle.textColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText




    return [slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4]
}

func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [Slide]) {
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
        slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
    }
}

/*
 * default function called when view is scolled. In order to enable callback
 * when scrollview is scrolled, the below code needs to be called:
 * slideScrollView.delegate = self or
 */
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

    let maximumHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width
    let currentHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x

    // vertical
    let maximumVerticalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height
    let currentVerticalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    let percentageHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = currentHorizontalOffset / maximumHorizontalOffset
    let percentageVerticalOffset: CGFloat = currentVerticalOffset / maximumVerticalOffset


    /*
     * below code changes the background color of view on paging the scrollview
     */
    //        self.scrollView(scrollView, didScrollToPercentageOffset: percentageHorizontalOffset)


    /*
     * below code scales the imageview on paging the scrollview
     */
    let percentOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: percentageHorizontalOffset, y: percentageVerticalOffset)


}




func scrollView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, didScrollToPercentageOffset percentageHorizontalOffset: CGFloat) {
    if(pageControl.currentPage == 0) {
        //Change background color to toRed: 103/255, fromGreen: 58/255, fromBlue: 183/255, fromAlpha: 1
        //Change pageControl selected color to toRed: 103/255, toGreen: 58/255, toBlue: 183/255, fromAlpha: 0.2
        //Change pageControl unselected color to toRed: 255/255, toGreen: 255/255, toBlue: 255/255, fromAlpha: 1


        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText



        slides[pageControl.currentPage].backgroundColor = Utils.Color.LigthViewBackGround

        let pageSelectedColor: UIColor = fade(fromRed: 81/255, fromGreen: 36/255, fromBlue: 152/255, fromAlpha: 1, toRed: 103/255, toGreen: 58/255, toBlue: 183/255, toAlpha: 1, withPercentage: percentageHorizontalOffset * 3)
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Utils.Color.BlueLabelText
    }
}


func fade(fromRed: CGFloat,
          fromGreen: CGFloat,
          fromBlue: CGFloat,
          fromAlpha: CGFloat,
          toRed: CGFloat,
          toGreen: CGFloat,
          toBlue: CGFloat,
          toAlpha: CGFloat,
          withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

    let red: CGFloat = (toRed - fromRed) * percentage + fromRed
    let green: CGFloat = (toGreen - fromGreen) * percentage + fromGreen
    let blue: CGFloat = (toBlue - fromBlue) * percentage + fromBlue
    let alpha: CGFloat = (toAlpha - fromAlpha) * percentage + fromAlpha

    // return the fade colour
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
}
```

}

Mi clase Slide es la siguiente

```
class Slide: UIView {


@IBOutlet weak var strLblTitle: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgCenterSlide: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var strLblSubTitle: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewBackGround: UIView!
```

}

y mis contrainsts son

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Desde ya cualquuier ayuda es bienvenida no entiendo porque no puede quedar cada view centrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recominedo cambiar tu codigo al sguiente.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.slides = createSlides()
    self.presenter.wfm = WorkflowManager.init(navigationController: self.navigationController)
}
```

El problema es que el slide que estas creando le estas asingnado el ancho de la vista del viewcontroller aun cuando no esta en pantalla por lo que tu vista no tiene el ancho de la pantalla del dispositivo que solo ocurre al aparecer la vista. tambien te recomendaria probar con `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` pero no estoy seguro que arregle el centrado. lo otro que podrias hacer seria añadir constrains via codigo.

Comment: podrias indicarme donde estoy colocandole el ancho de la pantalla ?a la vista del slide

Comment: cunado asignas el frame del slide le das el view.fram.width eso lo haces en el viewDidLoad pero aun los bound del screen no estan listos.

Comment: Excelente ya anduvo

Comment: no hay de que, me alegro te sirviera, hace un tiempo anduve viendo las diferencias entre los metodos de los viewcontroller y ahi lo vi claro, al principio de mi andadura ocn swift me paso mucho eso.